# Pass field value of original node in webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm using Drupal 8.7.8 and Webform 5.4.0. I have multiple section nodes that are displayed on course nodes. These are 2 different content types.

I'm adding webforms to sections, via the twig file conditionally (not all sections) with `{{ drupal_entity('webform', 'my_form_id') }}` and I need to pass the value of `field_code` of the section into a hidden field on the webform.

Once the form is rendered on the course page, the `field_code` value passed belongs to the course node rather than the section. How can I access the `field_code` value on the section?

I tried adding a hidden field with this token as the default `[webform_submission:node:field_code:value]`, which works when I test the form on the section, but when I test the form on the course (where the user will access it) I'm getting the `field_code` value of the course.

What's the best way to handle this? Is there a way to set the source entity to the content type that the form is on? Please let me know if I need to add more info.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible with `drupal_entity` because the fallback function of the drupal_entity extension accept 5 argument `$entity_type` `$id` `$view_mode` `$langcode` and `$check_access`, so i suggest to develop new extension like drupal_entity with another argument [field_machine_name => value] to set value of field

Comment: Thanks @berramou! I've edited my question to clarify how I'm using the token. I'm not setting the field value with drupal_entity, I'm just rendering the form on the twig with it. But, maybe I should be rendering it some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this with how I solved it in case anyone else has the same question. Maybe my question could be worded better though...

I was able to get this working with the Webform Node module.

I installed webform node. Then, I added a webform field to my content type. I selected the form I wanted as the default field settings. I selected the "Use this field's Content entity as the webform submission's source entity." checkbox.

I added my form to the display of the nodes I wanted it to be on in the content type's twig:

```
{% if node.field_name.entity.label == "My condition label" %}
  {{ content.field_name_of_webform_field }}
{% endif %}
```

Now, on my course page the same form appears for each section and I get the code for the section that the person filled-out the form on in the [webform_submission:source-entity:field_code:value] token!!

A couple of the resources that helped me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_ZyCOVKPqA
https://www.webwash.net/moving-forward-webform-drupal-8/#attaching-a-webform-to-a-node